# Is there a way to a new item to dropdownlist inline in .NET Core Kendo UI

Tags: c#, .net-core, kendo-ui

Please note the title, this is for the .NET Core version of the Kendo UI package, there may be ways to do this in other Kendo versions\libraries but I'm asking specifically for .NET Core.

I wasn't able to find anything like this in their demos but thought perhaps some kind of custom editor or something might make it possible. What I want is quite simple, a drop-down list that when opened will display:

```
--Add New Item--
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

if you select one of the items it works as it usually does, if you slect the first 'Add New Item' option it allows you to freeform enter a new option (say Item4) and then saves it and refreshes the list.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or Blazor?

Comment: @Max its an ASP.NET Core web application

Comment: Why don't you use a combo box with an onSave for inputted text that does not already exists in the dropdown?

Comment: @JamesS Thanks for the suggestion! I'm new to the library and I didn't realize there was both a combobox and a dropdownlist control. The former allows editing, so I just need to capture the onChange and then grab the current value and compare against what is in the combo's dataSource, if it doesn't exist I add to db. If you want to post this as your answer I will mark it correct

Comment: @snappymcsnap Exactly! Doing that should allow you to save the new input